# counting number of missing values for a row in SPSS Syntax

Tags: spss

I have a survey based data with each row representing a particular respondent and each column representing a response for a particular question in the survey. I have a dataset 72 columns and 2417 rows. For each row, I want to find the number of missing values for each row. What I am basically trying to assess is what % of missing values there are in each row.

```
COMPUTE counting_var = 0.
LOOP #i = 1 TO NCOLS(Dataset1).
   DO IF (MISSING(Dataset1(#i))).
      counting_var = counting_var + 1.
   END IF.
END LOOP.
counting_var = counting_var/NCOLS(Dataset1)
EXECUTE.
```

This code is written using SPSS syntax.
Through this code, I am trying to find the percent of survey questions a particular respondent has answered. If all the columns for a particular row are filled, it means that the respondent has answered all the questions.
However, this code is not working as I expect and is simply creating a new column called counting_var and filling it with 0s. I would be grateful if someone could help me fix this code. Unfortunately, I can only do this in SPSS syntax and no other programming language.

Comment: SPSS doesn't have a function `NCOLS`. Didn't you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

SPSS has a function `nmiss` that will get you the number of missing values in a row without a loop.
Assuming all the variables between `var1` and `var72` in the function are numerical, and consecutive in the data, this should work for you:

```
compute Pmiss=nmiss(var1 to var72)/72.
```

If you do have string variables in between, the following approach will work better:

```
* first we create a list of numeric variables.
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!allnums" /PROPERTIES TYPE=NUMERIC.
* now we count the number of variables in the list.
compute Nvrs = 0.
do repeat vr = !allnums .
   compute Nvrs = Nvrs + 1.
end repeat.
compute Pmiss=nmiss( !allnums ) / Nvrs.
```

Comment: My apologies, i believe I should have mentioned this, some variables between var1 to var72 as in the example above has some strings and some numeric variables.
in that case, nmiss does not seem to be working.